# Cropped image from storageFile becomes null in Release Mode but works on Debug mode

Tags: vb.net, uwp, windows-10

I have a problem with a function that extracts a cropped image from a **StorageFile** and save it to another file.
I'm using visual studio 2017, target version **10.0.16299** for the uwp app.

> In debug mode, it works.

In release mode, variable pixels becomes null (please, see the code!!)
why??

```
    Private Shared Async Function GetPixelData(decoder As BitmapDecoder, startPointX As UInteger, startPointY As UInteger, width As UInteger, height As UInteger, scaledWidth As UInteger,
        scaledHeight As UInteger) As Task(Of Byte())
        Dim transform As New BitmapTransform()
        Dim bounds As New BitmapBounds()
        bounds.X = startPointX
        bounds.Y = startPointY
        bounds.Height = height
        bounds.Width = width
        transform.Bounds = bounds
        transform.ScaledWidth = scaledWidth
        transform.ScaledHeight = scaledHeight
        Dim pix As PixelDataProvider = Await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, transform, ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb)
        Dim pixels As Byte() = pix.DetachPixelData()
        Return pixels
    End Function
```

' Get cropped image from storage file and save on new storagefile

```
Public Shared Async Function SaveCroppedBitmapAsync(originalImageFile As StorageFile, newImageFile As StorageFile, startPoint As Point, cropSize As Size) As Task
        Dim startPointX As UInteger = CUInt(Math.Floor(startPoint.X))
        Dim startPointY As UInteger = CUInt(Math.Floor(startPoint.Y))
        Dim height As UInteger = CUInt(Math.Floor(cropSize.Height))
        Dim width As UInteger = CUInt(Math.Floor(cropSize.Width))
        Using originalImgFileStream As IRandomAccessStream = Await originalImageFile.OpenReadAsync()

                Dim decoder As BitmapDecoder = Await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(originalImgFileStream)

                 If startPointX + width > decoder.PixelWidth Then
                startPointX = decoder.PixelWidth - width
            End If

            If startPointY + height > decoder.PixelHeight Then
                startPointY = decoder.PixelHeight - height
            End If

                       Using newImgFileStream As IRandomAccessStream = Await newImageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
                Dim pixels As Byte() = Await GetPixelData(decoder, startPointX, startPointY, width, height, decoder.PixelWidth,
                    decoder.PixelHeight)

                Dim encoderID As New Guid
                encoderID = Guid.Empty

                Select Case newImageFile.FileType.ToLower()
                    Case ".png"
                        encoderID = BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId
                        Exit Select
                    Case ".bmp"
                        encoderID = BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId
                        Exit Select
                    Case Else
                        encoderID = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId
                        Exit Select
                End Select

                Dim propertySet As New BitmapPropertySet()

                              If decoder.PixelWidth > 3000 Or decoder.PixelHeight > 3000 Then
                    Dim qualityValue As New BitmapTypedValue(0.4, PropertyType.Single)
                    propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue)
                Else
                    Dim qualityValue As New BitmapTypedValue(0.7, PropertyType.Single)
                    propertySet.Add("ImageQuality", qualityValue)
                End If

                            Dim bmpEncoder As BitmapEncoder = Await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderID, newImgFileStream, propertySet)

''''''''' Exception in this point,  pixel becomes null!!!! why????

                bmpEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, width, height, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY,
                        pixels)

                Await bmpEncoder.FlushAsync()

            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get error if you specified one of [encodingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.createasync#Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapEncoder_CreateAsync_System_Guid_Windows_Storage_Streams_IRandomAccessStream_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IKeyValuePair_System_String_Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapTypedValue___) (`propertySet` in your code) which is not supported by the image associated with the encoder when you create [BitmapEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder) object in the code

```
Dim bmpEncoder As BitmapEncoder = Await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderID, newImgFileStream, propertySet)
```

The `propertySet` you specified may be not supported. See the topic [Decode and encode image metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/image-metadata#decode-and-encode-image-metadata),

> •  For details on which properties are supported for which image file types, see [Windows Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props), [Photo Metadata Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wic/photo-metadata-policies), and [WIC image format native metadata queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wic/-wic-native-image-format-metadata-queries).
>
> •  [SetPropertiesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapProperties#Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapProperties_SetPropertiesAsync_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_1_) will fail with the error code 0x88982F41 if one of the requested properties is not supported by the image associated with the encoder.

You can modify your code without setting the property to make it work:

```
...

Dim bmpEncoder As BitmapEncoder = Await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderID, newImgFileStream)

Try
    Await bmpEncoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(propertySet)
Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try

...
```

In the **Try Catch** part, you can see the error message in the **Debug** code if the requested property is not supported.